# How to change 12-bits and 10-bits raw file to bitmap image using c#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, io, visual-c++-2010

I have 10-bits and 12-bits rawbayer (.raw) file. And i want to convert it to Bitmap image but i am unable to change it. 8-bits or 16-bits raw file changed easily but 10-bits or 12-bits can't be changed.

here is the code for 8-bits raw file to Bitmap.

```
private void DisplayImage08(string fileName) //Raw file name
    {
        // Open a binary reader to read in the pixel data. 
        // We cannot use the usual image loading mechanisms since this is raw 
        // image data.         
        try
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
            byte pixByte;
            int i;
            int iTotalSize = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

            // Get the dimensions of the image from the user
            ID = new ImageDimensions(iTotalSize); 
            width = Convert.ToInt32(ID.txtwidth);
            height = Convert.ToInt32(ID.txtheight);
            //panel1.Width = width;
            //panel1.Height = height;
            pictureBox1.Width = width;
            pictureBox1.Height = height;
            pix08 = new byte[iTotalSize];
                //pix08 = new byte[iTotalSize];

            for (i = 0; i < iTotalSize; ++i)
            {

                pixByte = (byte)(br.ReadByte());
                pix08[i] = pixByte;
            }
                br.Close();
               int bitsPerPixel = 8;
                stride = (width * bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

                // Single step creation of the image
                bmps = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null,
                    pix08, stride);
                //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();

               // img.Source = bmps;
                Bitmap bt = BitmapFromSource(bmps); //Change Bitmap source to Bitmap
                pictureBox1.Image = bt; //Display on pictureBox



                pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

But i want to change 12-bits or 10 bits raw file to Bitmap.

So please help me on this, that how can i change it?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: It seems you are ommitting the interresting part of the code. What are the implementation of `BitmapSource` and `BitmapFromSource`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer by no means, but this code will convert a 12 or 10 bit image, depending on how the data is packed, to a 8 bit image.

```
        // Input data read from file
        var pixels = ... 

        // Output
        var bytes = new byte[width * height];

        // Sort data
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                var index = i * 3 / 2;
                bytes[i] = pixels[index];
            }
            else
            {
                var index = (i * 3 + 1) / 2;
                bytes[i] = pixels[index];
            }
        }
```